# Trouble installing git LFS

Tags: github, git-lfs

I've installed LFS through Homebrew but when I set it up it returns

```
 Error: unknown command "install" for "git-lfs"
 Run 'git-lfs --help' for usage.
```

If I try to have it track a file type it returns

```
.swf is outside repository
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you run git-lfs install inside your repository ? If you cant do it that way, downlaod git-lfs [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/).